# Django rich text editor inside django template not for Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

How can I set rich text editor inside Django Template without using crispy form `{{form.media}}`. I am not using crispy form right now. What to do.

Comment: What about Summernote? https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote

Comment: How to integrate inside Django template?

Comment: https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote#form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any other method to do this. But, I can provide you the simplest solution.

Create a `forms.py` file inside your Django APP

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Order
class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['description']
```

Here, Order is your `Model Name`.

Inside your views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from order.models import Order
from .forms import OrderForm
# Create your views here.
def post_order(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        order_form = OrderForm()
        required_dict = {
            'form':order_form,
        }
        return render(request, "themes/order/order_post.html",required_dict)
```